# UIScrollview scrolls vertically despite correct contentSize

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, uiscrollview

I have a UIView within a UIScrollView. The UIScrollView has the following constraints:

```
-Top space to superview equals 0
-Leading space to superview equals 0
-Width equals 320.0f
-Height equals 45.0
```

The UIView has the following constraints:

```
-Top space to superview equals 0
-Bottom space to superview equals 0
-Leading space to superview equals 0
-Trailing space to superview equals 0
-Width equals 320.0
-Height equals 45.0
```

As far as I know, this should disable all scrolling. However, I am still able to scroll vertically to a maximum offset of 49.0. All sizes seem to be correct:

```
(lldb) po scrollView.contentSize
(width=420, height=45)
 {
  320

  45

}
(lldb) po scrollView
<UIScrollView: 0x10c332980; frame = (0 0; 320 45); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+TM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x10c333b80>; layer = <CALayer: 0x10c32c530>; contentOffset: {0, 49}>
(lldb) po contentView
<UIView: 0x10c332400; frame = (0 0; 320 45); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x10c3324c0>>
```

However the UIScrollView is still able to scroll vertically. Does anybody know how this is possible?

EDIT:

new info: problem occurs only on iOS 7.1, not iOS 6.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eventually I found out that the bottom content inset of the scrollview was not 0 but 49. It is still unclear how it gets to have a value, since it was not set in the layout editor, but I was able to disable vertical scrolling as follows:

```
[scrollView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
```

Answer (score 0):

UIView needs to turn off auto resize by calling the following method

`[uiview setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints];`

Comment: Still does not work. Also, if this would have been the problem, I would expect the contentSize to be incorrect, but it seems right.